# ARINC429 - Help generating differential ouput with SN75172?

Tags: differential

I'm trying to make a simple circuit setup to do a single-ended input to differential-balanced output of the ARINC429 spec, which is differential +5/-5v (10v p-p)...

ie spec is explained better here:  https://www.abaco.com/news/what-are-some-arinc-429-electrical-characteristics/n2097

single end input of '1' = out A is +5v, out B is -5v;
single end input of '0' = out A is -5v, out B is +5v

HOLT I/C makes a bunch of 429 drivers, receivers, etc, but they are quite pricey, and also hard to find right now.

Is it possible to replicate this using something like a SN75172 differen. driver?  I get a bit confused trying to understand how to do this..

Can I use the chip in a setup where Vcc = +5v, and GND is tied to -5v (ie I have a +5 and -5v power supply)?

Or do I need instead to do this with differential op-amp setup?

Or is my best solution really to use the HOLT IC, versus laying down a complex circuit?

**** FYI ***
This is for a LAB setup only, so I'm not worried about the EMI or lightning specs, etc, I just need to be able to do the differential signaling...**

Comment: Not knowing your application and that the ARINC429 is used in aircraft etc I would say you could not get it approved. I cannot make a recommendation in this area I am not qualified to do so.

Comment: Hi All, This is for a LAB environment only, just need to talk to 429 devices, so I don't care about the EMI and lightning, etc, I just need to do the differential levels..

Comment: I did an ARINC-429 interface for a simulator system back in the 90’s. I seem to recall I used something like the SN75102 as this was used by the flight qualified device I was connecting to.  The exact details are lost in time but I recall I was able to go to the local electronics shop and buy these devices (commercial grade). There was no specialised chips in the original equipment - the cpu was a military grade 8085 and stacks of SN54xx devices.

Comment: My advice would be to just spend the 20 bucks and use the Holt HI-8585 or HI-8586. Those parts are expressly built for this application. Even if you're an experienced EE designer, you'll spend many $$ in time trying to build something similar. You have to deal with the NULL state, and the outputs have to switch from -5V to +5V. A quick survey of available device types did not reveal any easy solutions with off-the-shelf devices. The Holt parts are in stock at DK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SN75172 works only with a 5 V supply; 10 V is likely to damage it. Furthermore, it is designed for RS-422/RS-485 and does not have rail-to-rail outputs.

One common solution to implement high-voltage logic is to use comparators (not op amps), but in your case, you need three voltage levels.

But your problem can be solved with analog switches. You have three power rails (5 V, 0 V, –5 V) and want to connect the A/B pins to any of them. The (CD/MC)[74HC4052](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/i-o-expansion-logic/analog-switches/74HC4052D.html) chip (available from several manufacturers) allows ±5 V and has two 4:1 switches. (Note: some other xx4052 chips do not have a V<sub>EE</sub> pin for a negative supply.)

Comment: Awesome.. thanks for this, I was kinda realizing the same thing, I need 3 states like you stated.... I was starting to think the same thing, just use muxes/switches..

Answer (score 0):

One of the EMI protection specs for ARINC429 is not met by any std CMOS driver. So you have a choice to design to add discrete parts to have a chance to meet these requirements or you don't meet the specs.

https://do160.org/lightning-induced-transient-susceptibility/

Comment: Hi All,  This is for a LAB environment only, just need to talk to 429 devices, so I don't care about the EMI and lightning, etc, I just need to do the differential levels..